# How to write a simple Powershell script to assign a user to an AD group

Tags: powershell, variables, active-directory-group, memberof

I just getting into writing Powershell scripts to perform repetitive tasks.  I want to write a script that will prompt for an ADgroup, and an AD userID, then add that user to the security group.

It starts like this:

```
  $SecurityGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the SecurityGroup name'
  $User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the userID'
  Get-ADGroup '$SecurityGroup' | Add-ADGroupMember -Members '$User'
  (GET-ADUSER –Identity '$user' –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
  Write-Host 'The user with userID '$user' has been added to the SecurityGroup '$SecurityGroup'
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code. Simply select it and click the `{}` button

Comment: so ... what is not working as expected?

Comment: Regarding line 4 I personally like the use of parenthesis to grab an object and access its property, but since you mention you are just getting into PS I offer a little teaching. 
 it can be rewritten like `GET-ADUSER –Identity '$user' –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf` If you insist on parenthesis method you could leave out the select-object part `(GET-ADUSER –Identity '$user' –Properties MemberOf ).MemberOf` to clean it up some

Comment: and don't forget to change or remove the single quotes around the variables (like I just did...)  `(GET-ADUSER –Identity $user –Properties MemberOf ).MemberOf`

Comment: So, I edited the script based on the information that you gave me.  and It seems to be working as intended now.  As I mentioned I'm just getting started and this will be very useful for day-to-day operations.  Next, I'd like to make emphasize some of the text by altering the color to draw more attention.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: $SecurityGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the SecurityGroup name'
$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the UserID '
Get-ADGroup $SecurityGroup | Add-AdGroupMember -Members $user
(Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties MemberOf ).MemberOf
Write-Host "The user with userID '$userID' has been added to the SecurityGroup '$SecurityGroup'"

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quotes surrounding your variables with double quotes " or remove the quotes completely.  The quotes are not necessary for your usage.

```
$user = "SomeUser"
Write-Host '$user' # Output: $user / variables inside single quotes will be left as-is
Write-Host "$user" # Output: SomeUser / variables inside double-quotes will be expanded
Write-Host $user   # Output: SomeUser
```

Line

```
Write-Host 'The user with userID '$user' has been added to the SecurityGroup  $SecurityGroup'
```

should look something like this (with double quotes surrounding)

```
Write-Host "The user with userID '$user' has been added to the SecurityGroup '$SecurityGroup'"
```

[About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1)